# How to fake or cheat that not running in debug mode when debugging in C#?

Tags: c#

I am developing C# winforms application.

It has a form with WebBrowser control.

This WebBrowser control should navigate a certain web page.

This web page has got an activex application.

The problem is when I am debugging my C# application, the activex finds it out and says,
"You are connecting this web site with debugging program. Please turn off your debugger."

And it just kills my application.

I think they are checking on the process weather I am running msvsmon.exe or vshost32.exe.

Does anyone have any idea to cheat this activex application?

Comment: Go back to good old fashion logging instead of running a debugger? ;)

Comment: Or good old [Kernel Debugging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff553382(v=vs.85).aspx) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are almost certainly NOT checking for msvsmon or vshost32.  There's a simple API call to test whether you are running under a debugger or not.  This is probably what they are calling, and there is no way around this if you aren't a seriously advanced kernel hacker.

Comment: Seriously advanced is seriously stretching it here. I'm not an advanced kernel hacker, and I've been around that flag when learning about disassembling code. All it is is a flag.

Comment: @MillieSmith - If you're going to modify the basic assembly code, sure, you can work around it.  That's still well beyond most people.

Answer (score 2):

Monitor all of the System API calls with a monitoring tool. See if `kernel32!IsDebuggerPresent` is called.

If you can find a way to inject assembly into your executable, you can use this, though I haven't figured it out yet so I can't test to see if your program still debugs (it should):

```
mov eax, fs:[30h]
mov byte [eax+2], 0
```

Source: http://www.symantec.com/connect/articles/windows-anti-debug-reference

Comment: I'm not sure if mov byte [eax + 2], 0 is current syntax, but you get the idea. Someone should edit this if they know assembler better than me.

Comment: There are several other ways apps can detect debuggers, and this may not be the only one.  For instance, there's also CheckRemoteDebuggerPresent (which, despite it's name does not mean Remote Debugging)

Comment: Feel free to add to my answer @MystereMan.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider wrapping your calls to the WebBrowser control with a [DebuggerStepThrough] attribute.  That way, the debugger won't be active when that code executes.

Not sure if it will work, but can't hurt to try.